# In swift, how can i remove an object from my tableview?

Tags: swift, dictionary, object, sections

I have a Data using this dictionary named : listDuJour from the class Donnees

```
class AlimentObject {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var nomAliment = "Nouvel aliment"
    var poids : Float = 100
    var calories : Float = 0
    var proteines : Float = 0
    var lipides : Float = 0
    var glucides : Float = 0
    var aRetinol : Float = 0
    var aBetacarotene : Float = 0
    var vitamineC : Float = 0
    var vitamineB1 : Float = 0
    var calcium : Float = 0
    var omega3 : Float = 0
    var comments : String = ""
    var premierBooleen: Bool
    var optimize: Bool
    

    
    init(nomAliment: String, poids: Float, calories: Float, proteines: Float, lipides: Float, glucides: Float, aRetinol: Float, aBetacarotene: Float, vitamineC: Float, vitamineB1: Float, calcium: Float, omega3: Float, comments:String, premierBooleen: Bool, optimize: Bool) {
        
        self.nomAliment = nomAliment
        self.poids = poids
        self.calories = calories
        self.proteines = proteines
        self.lipides = lipides
        self.glucides = glucides
        self.aRetinol = aRetinol
        self.aBetacarotene = aBetacarotene
        self.vitamineC = vitamineC
        self.vitamineB1 = vitamineB1
        self.calcium = calcium
        self.omega3 = omega3
        self.comments = comments
        self.premierBooleen = false
        self.optimize = false
    }
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(nomAliment: "Nouvel aliment", poids: 100, calories: 0, proteines: 0, lipides: 0, glucides: 0, aRetinol: 0, aBetacarotene: 0, vitamineC: 0, vitamineB1: 0, calcium: 0, omega3: 0, comments: "", premierBooleen: false, optimize: false)
    }
}

let begin01 = "11 09 2020"
let dateFormatter01 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter01.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"
let date01 = dateFormatter01.date(from: begin01)!

let begin02 = "12 09 2020"
let dateFormatter02 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter02.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"
let date02 = dateFormatter02.date(from: begin02)!

let begin03 = "15 09 2020"
let dateFormatter03 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter03.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"
let date03 = dateFormatter03.date(from: begin03)!


func dateSimplificator(with date: Date) -> Date {
    return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)
}

class Donnees {
        
        static var AlimentListWithSections = [[AlimentObject]]()
        
        static let list1 = [
            AlimentObject(nomAliment: "Blanc de poulet", poids: 100, calories: 108, proteines: 24, lipides: 1, glucides: 0, aRetinol: 8, aBetacarotene: 0, vitamineC: 0, vitamineB1: 0.08, calcium: 8, omega3: 0.03, comments: "sdsdsdsdsd sdsddsdsd", premierBooleen: false, optimize: false),
            AlimentObject(nomAliment: "Avocat", poids: 100, calories: 147, proteines: 1.76, lipides: 13.80, glucides: 1.57, aRetinol: 0, aBetacarotene: 55, vitamineC: 5.49, vitamineB1: 0.05, calcium: 11.2, omega3: 0.08, comments: "aaaaaaaaa sdsddsdsd", premierBooleen: false, optimize: false),
            AlimentObject(nomAliment: "Amandes", poids: 100, calories: 634, proteines: 21, lipides: 53, glucides: 8, aRetinol: 8, aBetacarotene: 1, vitamineC: 0.8, vitamineB1: 0.18, calcium: 248, omega3: 0.06, comments: "fffffff sdsddsdsd", premierBooleen: false, optimize: false)
            ]
        
        static let list2 = [
            AlimentObject(nomAliment: "Poivron Jaune", poids: 80, calories: 29.2, proteines: 1, lipides: 5.42, glucides: 0.21, aRetinol: 0, aBetacarotene: 120, vitamineC: 184, vitamineB1: 0.03, calcium: 11, omega3: 0.02, comments: "lllllllssss", premierBooleen: false, optimize: false),
            AlimentObject(nomAliment: "Saumon cru", poids: 100, calories: 192, proteines: 20.5, lipides: 12.2, glucides: 0, aRetinol: 8, aBetacarotene: 0, vitamineC: 1.6, vitamineB1: 0.21, calcium: 8, omega3: 1.79, comments: "eeeeeeee", premierBooleen: false, optimize: false)
            ]
        
        static let list3 : [AlimentObject] = [
            AlimentObject(nomAliment: "Avocat", poids: 100, calories: 147, proteines: 1.76, lipides: 13.80, glucides: 1.57, aRetinol: 0, aBetacarotene: 55, vitamineC: 5.49, vitamineB1: 0.05, calcium: 11.2, omega3: 0.08, comments: "aaaaaaaaa sdsddsdsd", premierBooleen: false, optimize: false),
            ]
        
        static let list4 : [AlimentObject] = [
            AlimentObject(nomAliment: "Amandes", poids: 100, calories: 108, proteines: 21, lipides: 53, glucides: 8, aRetinol: 8, aBetacarotene: 1, vitamineC: 0.8, vitamineB1: 0.18, calcium: 248, omega3: 0.06, comments: "fffffff sdsddsdsd", premierBooleen: false, optimize: false)
            ]
        
        static let list5 : [AlimentObject] = []
    
        static let listVide : [AlimentObject] = []

        static let listDuJour = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]
    static let nomsDesRepas: [String] = ["Petit Déjeuner", "Collation 11h", "Déjeuner", "Collation 16h", "Diner"]

    static func removeInstance(menuDuJour: [[AlimentObject]], attr1: String, attr2: Float) -> [[AlimentObject]] {
        let ListDuJourFiltree = menuDuJour.map {
            $0.filter { !($0.nomAliment == attr1 && $0.poids == attr2) }
        }
        return ListDuJourFiltree
    }
}
```

how could i delete from listDuJour theAliment object named "Poivron Jaune", with poids = "80", from the second section ?
I have 2 parametres to search my AlimentObject: the name and poids.
And the solution should not delete the empty sections in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove an instance of `Sample` (name of my example struct) you could do the following.

```
struct Sample {
    var attr1: String
    var attr2: String
}

let list1: [Sample] = [
    .init(attr1: "alasdfj", attr2: "asd"),
    .init(attr1: "qwer", attr2: "upoipp"),
    .init(attr1: "yxcv", attr2: "gfhj")
]
let list2: [Sample] = [
    .init(attr1: "Poviron Jaune", attr2: "80")
]

let list = [list1, list2]

let resultList = list.map {
    $0.filter { !($0.attr1 == "Poviron Jaune" && $0.attr2 == "80") }
}
```

And if you want to remove empty arrays which are inside `resultList`, too you could change the last part to:

```
let resultList = list.map {
    $0.filter { !($0.attr1 == "Poviron Jaune" && $0.attr2 == "80") }
}.filter { !($0.isEmpty) }
```

(Empty arrays occur, if all instances inside an subarray have been deleted)

So you should be able to do the following in order to get rid of the desired element inside `listDuJour`:

```
static func removeInstance(attr1: String, attr2: String) {
    listDuJour = listDuJour.map {
        $0.filter { !($0.nomAliment == attr1 && $0.poids == attr2) }
    }.filter { !($0.isEmpty) }
}
```

Or if you want to keep empty arrays (empty sections):

```
static func removeInstance(attr1: String, attr2: String) {
    listDuJour = listDuJour.map {
        $0.filter { !($0.nomAliment == attr1 && $0.poids == attr2) }
    }
}
```

Note that you will have to call `tableView.reloadData()` after you have removed the element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the object is deleted, but it' not the only one. when i apply your solution, all the sections in the array listDuJour which are empty are deleted. and that isn't possible for my tableView.

Comment: Did you test it in my dictionary?

Comment: ```AlimentListWithSections``` isn't a dictionary but a 2d array. And no I didn't test it, because I don't have your model class / struct (```AlimentObject```). But I assume that it should work...

Comment: unfortunately it'a not. i already add all the class, if you want to test your solution with all the necessary code

Comment: This code works just fine for me: ```let result = Donnees.removeInstance(menuDuJour: Donnees.listDuJour, attr1: "Poivron Jaune", attr2: 80)```. So ```result``` doesn't include the object with nomAliment: "Poivron Jaune" and poids: 80